# ESB 4.6.0. Router Mediator

Tags: mediator, wso2-esb

I used Router mediator in ESB 4.0.0. When we upgraded ESB to 4.6.0, router mediator doesn't work. And not exists in mediators List.

Is Router mediator still exist in ESB 4.6.0?

Answer (score 0):

The Router mediator has been deprecated. Use the Conditional Router instead (http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Conditional+Router+Mediator).